# Perl expression to block emails

Tags: perl

Before I begin: I have 0 clue what Perl is so please, don't "kill" me ;)
What I'm about to ask is based on info on my CPanel for my domain/hosting (I'm not a developer or anything)

So, on my CPanel I have this feature called "Box Trapper" to whitelist and blacklist emails.
They say that in order for me to block emails that come from a specific domain, I should use this:

***from .+@gapot.stream*** (so that would block all emails coming from @gapot.stream

now my question is: how would I write an expression if I wanted to block all emails that end with ***.stream***, regardless of the beginning being "gapot" or anything else, for example:

***@name1.stream***, ***@name2.stream*** and any combination that ends with .stream would be blocked

Hope it makes sense and someone here can help me (without being too technical, because I will not understand)

Thanks :)

Comment: These would be features/rules of your "Box Trapper" thing, so it seems.  I'd expect that there is some documentation for it, that'll explain what you can do. Perl is a programming language, which can also be used internally by other tools, but I do not at all understand from your question how it's involved with what you email-blocking need.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you do some reading on **regex** -- you will have a beautiful tool in your possession

Now in regex: [minimal basics]

```
. - any symbol
+ - 1 or more  (repeats)
* - 0 or more  (repeats)
{1,8} - 1 to 8 (repeats)
? - stop symbol (none greedy match)
```

Now your regex will be `.+@.+\.stream` :: any symbols followed with '@' followed by any symbols then '.' and ending in 'stream'. As you refer to e-mails then '@' is a critical element of pattern.

Sample of perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

while( <DATA> ) {
    print if /.+@.+\.stream/;
}

__DATA__
user1@subdomain1.stream
user2@subdomain2.stream
user3@sub.sub.domain.stream
user4@sub.domain.com
user5@sub.domain.org
user6@sub.sub.domain.net
```

For better understanding **regex** read following [chapter](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/lperl/ch07_01.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think that's exactly what I need :)
I will try it and if that works as expect, I will definitely come back here and let you know!

Comment: As promised, here's my comment: it works like a charm! I can't thank you enough for your help!

Comment: It should handle most email addresses -- even those which are incorrect: for example `!#$%^^&*()@!#$%^&*()_=.server.net`. In real life `.+` should be more specific something like `\w+` [letters and digits] or `[\w.]+` [letters,digits and .]. But valid emails will get _swallowed_ just fine.